# Bose QC35 fails to connect to XPS 15 9550 running Arch

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I am struggling with making my Bose Quiet Comfort 35 headset work on my XPS 15 9550 running Arch Linux. The headset works on my other computer (also running Arch), but I just can't figure out how to make it work on this laptop...

I first installed **pulseaudio-bluetooth**, **bluez**, **bluez-libs** and **bluez-utils**, then enabled and started the bluetooth service, without errors. I then set "**ControllerMode=bredr**" in "/etc/bluetooth/main.conf", restarted bluetooth and attempted to pair using blutoothctl. This failed, and led me to believe some firmware was missing. Installing **bluez-firmware** changed nothing, so I downloaded and installed the firmware for my card: aur.archlinux.org/**bcm20702a1-firmware**.

The headset pairs and connects now, but the connection is always and immediately dropped:

```
Device 04:52:C7:77:81:E3 Bose QuietComfort 35
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:77:81:E3 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 04:52:C7:77:81:E3 Connected: no
```

The same thing happens when using "blueman-applet", with the following error:

```
Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Input/output error...
```

In journalctl the following error appears:

```
Aug 20 21:38:18 duty bluetoothd[317]: Endpoint replied with an error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
```

Running "blueman-applet" as sudo reports the following error:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
```

Running "bluetoothctl" as sudo yields the connection followed by immediate disconnection result.

I've tried following suggestions from similar threads and mess around with "/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf", but to no effect.

I'm guessing it's a problem related to "pulseaudio-bluetooth", but am unable to debug any further, as I don't know what else can be done, nor where to look for more detailed error reports.

Might be worth noting that running "sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover" yields the following errors:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing notification daemons.

I believe this to be the case because `blueman` seems to be relying on system notifications instead of a regular dialog box for pairing devices. And you don't mention seeing any notifications.

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457499/how-to-identify-the-notification-daemon/457500#457500), where I luckily had one, but its notifications had no Confirm/Deny buttons.

Edit: [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/483634/21244) seems to be more complete (showing you the mechanism of Unity notifications).

In short: install `notification-daemon` (from Gnome) or [some other notification daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications#Standalone), then make sure it starts on startup, then restart.