# How to identify the notification daemon?

Tags: notifications, freedesktop, blueman

I want to see which notification daemon is running. This is because I want to replace it, since it does not properly confirm the notification from `blueman-applet`.

I mention that I am running the `i3` window manager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out myself.

1. Trigger the notification again
2. Open a console, and run `xwininfo` to find out which process created the notification window.
3. Uninstall that application, and install a different one (such as `notification-daemon` or `xfce4-notifyd`)
4. Restart.

In my case the culprit was `dunst`, which did not show buttons to Confirm / Deny the Bluetooth pairing.

Edit: [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/483634/21244) seems to be more complete (showing you the mechanism of Unity notifications).

Comment: Nice solution, I would not have thought of this approach myself.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Thanks; but I'm still hoping someone knows an even better solution

Comment: @danuker, so have you found no way to use `dunst` and deal with confirm/deny buttons?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I didn't spend ANY time at all to figure out if buttons can be enabled. I don't remember installing it, and can't be bothered to learn and tinker with yet another basic tool.


Perhaps they can be enabled, but I prefer a notification daemon which shows an interrogation's buttons by default.